# androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat cannot be cast to androidx.preference.PreferenceGroup

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences, preferencescreen

So I'm trying to make an options menu in my android app but when I click on it in the emulator the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat cannot be cast to androidx.preference.PreferenceGroup
```

I don't really know what I am doing wrong here, I hope somebody knows.

The settings activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String KEY_PREF_EXAMPLE_SWITCH = "example_switch";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content,
                        new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

The fragment class

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState,
                                    String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }

}
```

methods in my MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        // Launch SettingsActivity
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

EDIT
Here is also my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SwitchPreferenceCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="vega_preference"
        android:summaryOff="@string/vega_off_string"
        android:summaryOn="@string/vega_on_string"
        android:title="@string/vega_switch_title" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="vegan_preference"
        android:summaryOff="@string/vegan_off_string"
        android:summaryOn="@string/vegan_on_string"
        android:title="@string/vegan_switch_title" />
</SwitchPreferenceCompat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat cannot be cast to androidx.preference.PreferenceGroup`

The snippet `setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)` is what raises that as it expects a `PreferenceGroup` instead of a preference view. Where `SwitchPreferenceCompat` is not `PreferenceGroup`.

That is because you used a `SwitchPreferenceCompat` as the root element of settings screen. Instead you need to use the `PreferenceScreen` which extends from `PreferenceGroup`.

So to fix this you need to make sure that the root element of your preference layout is `PreferenceScreen`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a bit tired so I must've just put it in the wrong place haha.